# Python Super Function - Different than usual

Tags: python

First I'll make a confession, I don't fully grasp the Super function in python.
Well, I know that it is used to gain access to inherited methods – from a parent or sibling class, and I use this function every time the same manner, when I'm creating a class:

```
class ClassName(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self)
         super(ClassName, self).__init__()
```

Now I encountered those 2 cases, which I don't understand:

1. The first is a "super" inside the init function, but with arguments inside:

   ```
   super(ClassName, self).__init__(self.filters, self.filters*2, 3, padding=1, bias=False, **kwargs)
   ```

2.The second is a "super" inside the forward function:

```
    offsets = super(ClassName, self).forward(x)
```

Please help me understand those cases, and I hope that through them I'll be able to grasp the super function much better.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what difference you are making here. In all cases, you call the relevant method from the parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@albert905, the super() function is used to access another Class function in the way you mentioned.

What you should understand is that you call this function the same way you call any function inside the class.

So if I have a parent class such as:

```
class ParentClass():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
```

Then, when you create a Child Class, and call the super method, you should add the same arguments that the parent class asks for, so a possible Child Class would be:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self)
         super(ClassName, self).__init__("var1 Value", "var2 Value")
```

You see that I passed the same arguments I would if I just instantiated the Parent Class, like in:

```
parent1 = ParentClass("var1 Value", "var2 Value")
```

The logic is the same for any function you use from the ParentClass. If it requires arguments, you should pass them with the `super` function.

For your example, you passed `x` on the call for `forward` class, because this function requires an argument.

PS: In the case of the first class you mentioned, `class ClassName(nn.Module)`, you should understand exactly the methods implemented by `nn.Module` in order to understand what the functions called by `super()` will require in terms of arguments